# VScode detects file as JavaScript, but doesn't highlight undefined functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

The following JavaScript is saved into a file called `test.js`

```
iDontExist();
```

(this is the entire file)

VSCode doesn't show the highlights for the `iDontExist` function, which isn't imported or required anywhere.

**How can I make VScode highlight the undefined function?**

[image]

Note other Intellisense features (eg, inspecting imports) in JS files (not TS files) seem to work fine:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "highlight"? Do you maybe want to use typescript, or [a linter](https://i.imgur.com/lxOekuQ.png)?

Comment: I think you need to install jshint https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint

Comment: Install the ESlint extension for your VS code.

Comment: @m3hran that fixed it. I wasn't sure what was intellisense and what was eslint. Want to add your comment to an answer and I'll mark it as accepted?

Comment: Default javascript has no type checks, no safety nets, no nothing. That's good, when you need a very short script, maybe even in node repl, and just "want to get things done quick"/"do things". There, if you have some implicit global `iDontExist`, you don't need to first explicitly declare everywhere that "yeah that exists, stop complaining". For anything else, i'd always recommend typescript+linter.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I understand and sometimes use typescript, but this is a JS codebase with extensive unit tests (which catches more errors than TS type checks would).

Comment: These all catch different categories of problems. While in this case, the linter somewhat overlaps with typescript (ts would also complain, in a `.ts` file, that rule should be disabled), the general sentiment is linting for style and bad practices, typescript (or flow, ...) for type checking, unit tests for semantic mistakes. They work well with each other. However, i understand, that for large javascript code-bases, a migration can be too difficult and work-intensive.

Comment: @ASDFGerte you're also duplicating the work of the unit tests with the type checks, and adding more work for developers who have to work on JS/TS incompatibilities (of which there are many) - see Eric Elliot's writing on the topic. My point is - **this is a JS question. Not a place for TypeScript advocacy.** We can continue this discussion elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Undefined functions in VSCode aren't automatically highlighted when they are undefined because of [globals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), this includes a totally different setup to get the highlighting running:

Using [the ESlint Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) to get undefined functions or errors highlighted.

[image]

You can also use [`ts-check`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files), which is what I use and has been working fine.

Comment: Hi Ayo -- I just saw your talk at NVIDIA.  I know this isn't the normal channel to get in touch. But thanks for your efforts for SO and the African developer community.